# What to do now?

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, mount, filesystem

```
/dev/sdal contains a file system with errors, check forced.

/dev/sda1:

Inode 12849237 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower. IGNORED. /dev/sda1: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. (i.e., without -a or -p options)

fsck exited with status code 4

The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3) built-in shell (ash)

Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

Comment: Hello. The title means nothing. What is the question?

Comment: So have you run a manual fsck?

Comment: At the initramfs prompt, type `fsck -f /dev/sda1` or `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`, then `reboot`.

Comment: Not helping suggest something else plz

Comment: This are not working,pls suggest something else

Comment: What is manual fsck???

Comment: Please edit the title of your question so it reflects the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because your system crashed, possibly because you forced it to shut down by holding a power button or something.  A manual fsck just tells you to type `fsck /dev/sda1`, press enter, keep saying "yes" to everything, and then restart when you're finished.